# What's correct "I live in a village" or "I live at a village"

Tags: word-choice

I've read that "at" is used for relatively small places like (villages, restaurants, etc..), but what about this situation, I feel that "in" fits better, but I'm not a native speaker so I'm not sure.

Comment: Generally, "in a village" is more idiomatic and less confusing to the listener.  There are cases where "at a village" might be preferred, but they would be situations such as describing where a traffic accident occurred, etc.

Comment: ***at*** refers to a ***point*** (in space, ***at** the end of my road*; in time, ***at** six o'clock)*. ***on*** and ***in*** are "surface" and "container" metaphors, and sometimes you get a choice of preposition (***on** Monday, **on** the High Street*; ***in** December, **in** the High Street*).

Answer (score 0):

"at" is used when you want to include specificity to your statement. In your case, "village" is not specific but a generic term that is used to describe a place or a neighbourhood but not identify the place.

So in this case, "I live in a village" is the correct usage. Take a look at [this](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/using-at-vs-in-for-place-and-time-correctly.html).

Comment: in my case, It says the location of the village relative to the country, ex: "North France"

Comment: Right. It is still a neighbourhood and not a specific village as such. So in would be the choice.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with specificity. You'd still use "in" if you said "I live in the village of Woodbury"

Answer (score 0):

In general "at" is used when you are specifying the exact and complete location of something. "In" is used when the location given is inexact or incomplete.

> Harry Potter lived **at** 4 Privet Drive, Little Whinging.

4 Privet Drive is exactly his home - anything inside that address is his home, anything not inside it is not his home.

> Harry Potter lived **in** Little Whinging.

Harry's home is inside the village of Little Whinging, but there are parts of the village that are not his home. You could also say that Harry Potter lived "in" a village or "in" Surrey, but not "at" a village or "at" Surrey.

This can get a little complicated and there are exceptions. You would normally use "at" when specifying an exact address, even if that address is divided into separate residences. You might say King Charles III lived "in" Buckingham Palace because parts of it are used for things other than his residence, but "at" would probably be acceptable too.

Comment: There are other considerations between **at** and **in**. Harry Potter lived **in** the Dursley's house **at** 4 Privet Drive.